# Navbar header buttons get long in medium size screens

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Large Screen(Good)
[image: http://imgur.com/vQjgedc]

Medium Screen(Bad)
[image: http://imgur.com/tZKBPXK]

Small Screen(Good)
[image: http://imgur.com/ng2368s]

Small Screen Button Dropdown(Bad)
[image: http://imgur.com/POdRxOR]

I tried making a plunkr and I'll still link it but it's getting a ton of errors but it has my css and html in it so you can still see that. I am trying to make a mobile responsive navbar and for some reason when I get around medium size screen it the buttons get 1000+ px long and take up huge amounts of room. Tried looking in computed tab in chrome dev tools but it won't show me whats causing the enormous width. Also it does the width is huge on the dropdown too at small screens.

HTML:

```
<section class="navbarheader">
            <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" style="z-index: 10">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <!--Navbar Brand-->
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#desktop-nav">
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <a href="/" class="navbar-brand">
                            <span class="navbarLogo">
                                <img src="/images/propulstion%20navigation-bar-logo.png" />
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <!--End of Navbar Brand-->
                    <!--Desktop Navbar-->
                    <div id="desktop-nav" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <!--Settings Dropdown-->
                            <li id="settings" class="dropdown" uib-dropdown>
                                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="nav-icon dropdown-toggle" uib-dropdown-toggle tooltip="Settings" tooltip-placement="bottom">
                                    <span class="mdi mdi-settings"></span>
                                </a>
                                <ul uib-dropdown-menu class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li class="dropdown-header">Settings</li>
                                    <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "SiteSettings", new { Area = "SiteSettings" })"><span>Site Settings</span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "SiteAdmin", new { Area = "Administration" })"><span>Site Administration</span></a></li>
                                 </ul>
                            </li>
                            <!--End of Settings Dropdown-->
                            <!--LoginPartial Dropdown-->
                            <li id="loginDropDown" class="dropdown hidden-md" uib-dropdown>@Html.Partial("_LoginPartial") </li>
                            <!--End of LoginPartial Dropdown-->
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <!--End of Desktop Navbar-->
                    <!--Mobile NavBar-->
                    @*<div id="mobile-nav" class="visible-xs-block">
                        <div class="dropdown open mobilenav-download-menu">
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li class="dropdown" uib-dropdown>
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="nav-icon dropdown-toggle" uib-dropdown-toggle tooltip="Settings" tooltip-placement="bottom">
                                        <span class="mdi mdi-settings"></span>
                                    </a>
                                    <ul uib-dropdown-menu class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li class="dropdown-header">Settings</li>
                                        <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "SiteSettings", new { Area = "SiteSettings" })"><span>Site Settings</span></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "SiteAdmin", new { Area = "Administration" })"><span>Site Administration</span></a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>*@
                    <!--End of Mobile NavBar-->
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Okay I'm getting errors saying I need code to link a plunkr.

Comment: change col-* classes to match your breakpoints at each side, you can use xs-md-sm-lg depending on the size.

Comment: I dont use any. Let me display the HTML. How should I show my css? There is a ton in there so I can't just go pick out the navbar things.

Comment: Well then that's your problem, you need to use bootstraps `col-` classes.

Comment: So it would be like "<li id="loginDropDown" class="dropdown col-md-3" uib-dropdown>@Html.Partial("_LoginPartial") </li>" then right?

Answer (score 0):

You can manually define your styling similar to bootstrap for your `navbarheader`. Just add these stylings in your **CSS** file and use these **classes** wherever or on whatever **Element** you want to.

```css
@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  .col-md-1, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12 {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
  .col-md-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .col-md-11 {
    width: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-10 {
    width: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-9 {
    width: 75%;
  }
  .col-md-8 {
    width: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-7 {
    width: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-md-5 {
    width: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-4 {
    width: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-md-2 {
    width: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-1 {
    width: 8.33333333%;
  }
 
  .pull-left {
    float: left !important;
  }
  
  }
```

You can also Add other classes or rename as per your use if you want, but for **Medium** sized devices, it will be the best practice.

Hope this helps!